# Best way to compute regular period averages based on irregular timeseries data

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series, timedelta

**Question:**

I have a timeseries dataset with irregular intervals, and I want to compute the averages per regular time interval.

What is the best way to do this in Python?

**Example:**

Below a simplified dataset as a Pandas series:

```
base = pd.to_datetime('2021-01-01 12:00')

mydict = {
    base: 5,
    base + timedelta(minutes=5): 10,
    base + timedelta(minutes=7): 12,
    base + timedelta(minutes=12): 6,
    base + timedelta(minutes=25): 8
}

series = pd.Series(mydict)
```

Returns:

```
2021-01-01 12:00:00     5
2021-01-01 12:05:00    10
2021-01-01 12:07:00    12
2021-01-01 12:12:00     6
2021-01-01 12:25:00     8
```

**My solution:**

I want to resample this to a regular 15 minute interval and take the mean. I can do this by first resampling to a very small interval (seconds) and then resampling to 15 minutes:

```
series.resample('S').ffill().resample('15T').mean()
```

Returns:

```
2021-01-01 12:00:00    8.200000
2021-01-01 12:15:00    6.003328
```

It does not feel Pythonic to first resample to a small interval before sampling to the desired interval. And I expect it also get quite slow with large datasets that require high accuracy. **Is there a better way to do this?**

**P.S.** In case you are wondering: If you resample to 15 minutes right away you do not get the desired result:

```
series.resample('15T').mean()
```

Returns:

```
2021-01-01 12:00:00    8.25
2021-01-01 12:15:00    8.00
```

Comment: In your example does the first row imply a value of 5 from `2021-01-01 12:00:00` to `2021-01-01 12:05:00` and a value of 10 from `2021-01-01 12:05:00` to `2021-01-01 12:07:00` etc, i.e. is your data describing moments in time, or intervals?

Comment: Yes, you are correct, so it's describing intervals.

Answer (score 2):

If the timestamps in your data represent breakpoints between intervals, then your data describes a step function.  You can use a package called [staircase](https://staircase.dev) which is built upon `pandas` and `numpy` for analysis with step functions.

Using the setup code you provided, create a `staircase.Stairs` object from `series`.  These objects represent step functions are to `staircase` as `Series` are to `pandas`.

```
import staircase as sc

sf = sc.Stairs.from_values(initial_value=0, values=series)
```

There are lots of things you can do with Stairs objects, including plotting

```
sf.plot(style="hlines")
```

[image: plot of stepfunction]

Next create your 15 minute bins, eg

```
bins = pd.date_range(base, periods=5, freq="15min")
```

`bins` looks like this

```
DatetimeIndex(['2021-01-01 12:00:00', '2021-01-01 12:15:00',
            '2021-01-01 12:30:00', '2021-01-01 12:45:00',
            '2021-01-01 13:00:00'],
            dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='15T')
```

Next we slice the stepfunction into pieces with the bins and take the mean.  This is analogous to groupby-apply with dataframes in pandas.

```
means = sf.slice(bins).mean()
```

`means` is a `pandas.Series` indexed by the bins (a `pandas.IntervalIndex`) with the mean values

```
[2021-01-01 12:00:00, 2021-01-01 12:15:00)    8.200000
[2021-01-01 12:15:00, 2021-01-01 12:30:00)    6.666667
[2021-01-01 12:30:00, 2021-01-01 12:45:00)    8.000000
[2021-01-01 12:45:00, 2021-01-01 13:00:00)    8.000000
dtype: float64
```

If you just wanted to have the start points of the interval as the index then you can do this

```
means.index = means.index.left
```

Or similarly, use endpoints.  If you're feeding this data into a ML algorithm then use endpoints to avoid data leakage.

**summary**

```
import staircase as sc

sf = sc.Stairs.from_values(initial_value=0, values=series)
bins = pd.date_range(base, periods=5, freq="15min")
means = sf.slice(bins).mean()
```

**note**:
I am the creator of staircase.  Please feel free to reach out with feedback or questions if you have any.

Comment: Thank you Riley, this is exactly what I was looking for!